# SSIS can't convert because of potential loss of data

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I am trying to upload a CSV file through SSIS but it gives me error which I am unable to solve.

These are the errors that I get:

> [OLE_DST - Insert into stg_hcd_hcms_xls_fm01 [196]] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005.
>
> An OLE DB record is available. Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0"
> Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "Invalid character value for cast specification".
>
> [OLE_DST - Insert into stg_hcd_hcms_xls_fm01 [196]] Error: There was an error with OLE_DST - Insert into stg_hcd_hcms_xls_fm01.Inputs[OLE DB Destination Input].Columns[report_date] on OLE_DST - Insert into stg_hcd_hcms_xls_fm01.Inputs[OLE DB Destination Input]. The column status returned was: "The value could not be converted because of a potential loss of data.".
>
> [OLE_DST - Insert into stg_hcd_hcms_xls_fm01 [196]] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_INDUCEDTRANSFORMFAILUREONERROR.  The "OLE_DST - Insert into stg_hcd_hcms_xls_fm01.Inputs[OLE DB Destination Input]" failed because error code 0xC0209077 occurred, and the error row disposition on "OLE_DST - Insert into stg_hcd_hcms_xls_fm01.Inputs[OLE DB Destination Input]" specifies failure on error. An error occurred on the specified object of the specified component.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
>
> [SSIS.Pipeline] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PROCESSINPUTFAILED.  The ProcessInput method on component "OLE_DST - Insert into stg_hcd_hcms_xls_fm01" (196) failed with error code 0xC0209029 while processing input "OLE DB Destination Input" (209). The identified component returned an error from the ProcessInput method. The error is specific to the component, but the error is fatal and will cause the Data Flow task to stop running.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
>
> [FF_SRC for FM01 [23]] Error: The attempt to add a row to the Data Flow task buffer failed with error code 0xC0047020.
>
> [SSIS.Pipeline] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PRIMEOUTPUTFAILED.  The PrimeOutput method on FF_SRC for FM01 returned error code 0xC02020C4.  The component returned a failure code when the pipeline engine called PrimeOutput(). The meaning of the failure code is defined by the component, but the error is fatal and the pipeline stopped executing.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RVBdH.png)

I tried to breakdown the data into smaller blocks, from 35356 rows to 2500 rows, it works without any error. No changes were made to the source files except that 2 columns report_date and count were interchanged, but that one should not be the cause of the error I guess. If so, it should not be working for a smaller row number I guess.

-I had changed the table view fast load into table/view but still no change.

Could anyone help. Thanks

Comment: What is the type of report_date field? If it is of date type, convert it to string and test. If the insertion is done, you have invalid data in csv file. Using the `ISDATE()` function, you can find the wrong data.

Comment: The first error says invalid character... I'd start with that.

Comment: @MostafaNZ ,Dale K thanks for the replies. After changing the datatype , I could get the data in db and could find out that it is an error in  another column due to a comma causing the data to shift to the right columns and cause invalid data.

Comment: *.csv/txt flat files always have host of problems where column delimiters, column separators, invisible characters like null terminators \0, special characters based on encoding, and line breaks are in the middle of the actual data.
The most reliable format for data feeds is XML enforced by XSD. An XSD plays a role of a data contract between sender and receiver. It will guarantee proper data format/shape, and enforce data quality.

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky,thanks for the info. will be useful to suggest for the future projects.

Comment: @MostafaNZ or others who can help. I am able to connect with a new flat file connection in the ssis and the load the flat file which could be loaded into the db. But when I  load the batch job to run in sql server to auto pick the csv file and load, it gives me error.Any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: What is the text of the error?

Comment: @MostafaNZ        DFT - Process file:Error: There was an error with OLE_DST - Insert into stg_hcd_hcms_xls_fm01.Inputs[OLE DB Destination Input].Columns[count] on OLE_DST - Insert into stg_hcd_hcms_xls_fm01.Inputs[OLE DB Destination Input]. The column status returned was: "The value could not be converted because of a potential loss of data.".   but this error is the same as previous one. But the same data I am able to load manually now without any error after the previous error was rectified.

Comment: There are a few more errors in the log. but this is the one I suppose is the main one.

Comment: if this is an error, then why am I able to load manually in the ssis the same data without any error?

Comment: Try to build the table using ssis . This table is built using the fields read from the source file

Comment: @MostafaNZ, tks. will do it.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the issue by rebuilding the table with the new file where the columns have been interchanged. The re build was the key here. Afterwards when I tried to run, the package was extracted and loaded successfully.